# How to make one keypress trigger multiple events separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**TL;DR:** Each time a user presses the space key, I want the next line of dialogue to appear.

**Context:** I've just started learning to code in the last few weeks (first basic html & css, now JS). I've mostly been using freecodecamp and YouTube. To help me learn more creatively, I thought I'd start making a little text-based game (BOTW-themed, because it's my favourite actual game). I have all sorts of ideas for things I'd like to implement later, but I'm a bit stuck early on.

**The problem:**  At the beginning of the game, I want to have some lines of dialogue, that I'll .append into the document, each time the user presses the space key. The basic code looks like this:

```js
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 32) {
    $('#gameText').append("<h2>It sounds familiar...</h2>");
  }
});

$(document).keyup(function(e1) {
  if (e1.which == 32) {
    $('#zelda').append("<h3>Link...</h3>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<h1> You hear an faint, incorporeal voice, carried by the wind... </h1>
<script>
  function(e)
</script>
<h2 id="gameText"></h2>
<h3 id="zelda"></h3>
<p> Press <b>space</b> to continue</p>
```

The problem with that is that a single press of the space key will trigger all the .keyup events at once; whereas I want to bring the lines in one at a time.

I've tried a few different ideas, such as creating a number variable, and incrementing it on each keypress, then using a switch statement to select each line of dialogue.

```js
let spacecount = 0;
while (spacecount < 10) {
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32) {
      spacecount++;
    }
  });

  switch (spacecount) {
    case 1:
      $('#gameText').append("<h2>It sounds familiar...</h2>");
      break;
    case 2:
      $('#zelda').append("<h3>Link...</h3>");
      break;
  }
}
```

But it's just not happening, and I'm stumped. Apologies for the long-winded post.

Comment: Since it's a dialog, the order is completely fixed, else the text won't make sense. So I would just put all the text inside an object and all those objects inside an array. Then you can `.shift()` out the first remaining text object every time the space key is pressed. Then you can reuse alot of the code ( just with different input arrays ) for both the gameText and the zelda fields. The added advantage is that you can model the entire adventure inside that array, including like player choices. If yes, continue with subarray A, else continue with subarray B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a more elegant solution. Instead of huge switch blocks you could have an array (or object) of dialogue lines and a counter to mark your next line.

```js
const dialogue = [
    ["#gameText", "<h2>It sounds familiar...</h2>"],
    ["#zelda", "<h3>Link...</h3>"]
];

let counter = 0;

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32) {
      if (counter >= dialogue.length)
        return;

      $(dialogue[counter][0]).append(dialogue[counter][1]);
      counter++; 
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="gameText"></div>
<div id="zelda"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think putting logic inside event listener should solve the problem:

```
let spacecount = 0;

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (spacecount < 10 && e.which == 32) {
        switch (spacecount) {
            case 1:
              $('#gameText').append("<h2>It sounds familiar...</h2>");
              break;
            case 2:
              $('#zelda').append("<h3>Link...</h3>");
              break;
        }

        spacecount++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same event for executing two functions. jQuery will execute both functions when the button is pressed. You need to set a counter and count the event.